# Makefile for different .cpp files in different folders

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, gcc

I have the following folder structure:

Project project:

- folder1

  - sourceFile1_1.cpp
  - sourceFile1_2.cpp
- folder2

  - sourceFile2.cpp
- folder3

  - sourceFile3.cpp
- main.cpp
- makefile

And I'd like to create a makefile which builds the project. The source files can have dependencies among them, but there is not any cyclic dependency.

This is the makefile I have right now:

```
all: project.exe

clean:
    rm main.o project.exe

project.exe: main.o
    g++ -g -o main main.o

main.o:
    g++ -c -g  main.cpp
```

But when I run it, I get `Cannot open include file: 'whatever....h': No such file or directory`

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: use `-I` option to specify path to headers

Answer (score 1):

`cannot open include file`, means that the compiler was not able to find the file.  The compiler uses the include path to search for include files.  You can look at the documentation [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) for more information about how you can set this include path.